# How to display IP in serial monitor using AT command with ESP8266 in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, telnet, at-command, esp8266

I'm connecting to an ESP8266 in Arduino. I want to connect the wifi module with Arduino. I want to find the IP using AT+CIFSR. How to print the IP using an AT command in the serial monitor? To connect with a telnet app, the IP is needed to insert in Android phone.

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
String ssid = "connectify-krish";
String password = "12345678";
SoftwareSerial esp(10, 11);
void setup() {
  int len;
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp.begin(9600);
  reset();
  esp.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  if (esp.find("OK")) Serial.println("Module Reset");
  esp.println("AT+RST");
  delay(1000);
  if (esp.find("OK")) Serial.println("Reset");
  esp.println("AT+RST");
  delay(1000);
  String cmd = "AT+CWJAP=\"" + ssid + "\",\"" + password + "\"";
  Serial.println(cmd);
  String site= "www.google.com";
  String ping = "AT+PING=\"" + site + "\"";
  esp.println(ping);
  if (esp.find("OK")) Serial.println("CONNECTED WIFI");
  String ip = "AT+CIFSR";
  esp.println(ping);
  if (esp.find("OK")) Serial.println("ip is");
}

void reset() {
  if(esp.available()) {
    // check if the esp is sending a message
    while(esp.available()) {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
      char c = esp.read(); // read the next character.
      Serial.write(c);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: Is your question how to read the serial response from the ESP? There's nothing special about the AT command versus reading any other serial data. The Arduino Serial documentation shows you how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending the AT command

```
String ip = "AT+CIFSR";
esp.println(ping);
if (esp.find("OK")) Serial.println("ip is");
```

should be

```
String ip = "AT+CIFSR";
esp.println(ip);
Serial.print("ip is ");
// Loop through all the data returned
while(esp.available()) {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
      char c = esp.read(); // read the next character.
      Serial.write(c);
}
Serial.println("");
```